# Get hash value without assigning it to a variable

Tags: javascript

In javascript, I get an error when doing:

```
{O: 'Ida', I: 'Regreso'}['O']
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is expected result?

Comment: See the "NOTE" at: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-expression-statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `{O: 'Ida', I: 'Regreso'}` isn't an object in this context, it's a block with the label `O` followed by the string literal expression `'Ida'`, then a comma operator, with another label (which is a syntax error at this point) and another string literal expression.

(This is the source of the common WAT with `[] == {}` vs `{} == []`, in the first case, it's "array literal equals object literal", in the second it's "empty block equals array literal" (which is a syntax error))

The reason for that is because of parsing context, `{O: 'Ida', I: 'Regreso'}` would only be considered an object when placed in an expression context. One of the most common ways to do that, is surround it with parentheses, like so:

```js
console.log(({O: 'Ida', I: 'Regreso'})['O'])
```

You can see how your expression is interpreted **[with](https://astexplorer.net/#/5X47lvwWuT/1)** and **[without](https://astexplorer.net/#/5X47lvwWuT)** the parentheses (round brackets).